# Intellij/GWT Starting a gwt application without permutations

Tags: java, gwt, jetty

I want to start my gwt application on dev mode using an external jetty and the gwt compilation server (using -noserver).

Starting the webserver (jetty + gwt war) with 3 permutations (user.agent=safari) takes 250s with options :

- -Dgwt.compiler.skip=true
- -Dgwt.draftCompile=true
- -Dgwt.compiler.localWorkers=8
- -Dgwt.compiler.optimizationLevel=0

and in the file MyProject.gwt.xml

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari" />
```

Then I start the dev mode, and the gwt compilation server does 2 more permutations when I want to refresh the client.

Is it possible to avoid permutations while launching the jetty ?

I know that -Dgwt.compiler.skip=true avoid permutations but it doesn't generate the minimum js needed by the gwt compilation server, MyProject directory containing files like MyProject.nocache.js or MyProject.devmode.js is missing so I can't ask the compilation server to do his job while on my browser.

If I use the option -Dgwt.compiler.skip=true, my webserver starts in 30s but I am stuck.

I don't know why gwt needs to do permutations while launching the webserver, isn't that the gwt compilation server's job on dev mode ?

edit : I think I have the same problem than this person in 2014 https://groups.google.com/g/google-web-toolkit/c/p9BGyLxiLkE

Except I am using gwt 2.9

Comment: Can you share the generated compilation-mappings.txt file, and the build log to confirm what is happening here?

Comment: Hi where can I find this file ? In the code server html page when I click on the link with the module's name I only have 3 files MyModule.nocache.js
MyModule.recompile.nocache.js
clear.cache.gif

Comment: @ColinAlworth I think my problem is the same problem than this person in 2014 https://groups.google.com/g/google-web-toolkit/c/p9BGyLxiLkE

Comment: The file is built to the same output directory as your MyModule.nocache.js when you do a build. Start your jetty as you describe above, then share the file that is generated. With that said, you should not need to generate GWT production JS when starting your own jetty - how are you starting jetty that this is a requirement, and what does "I am stuck" actually mean about why super dev mode isn't working?

Comment: @ColinAlworth The thing is the MyModule directory, with MyModule.nocache.js and others files, is not generated. If I remove the parameter -Dgwt.compiler.skip=true it's ok but it runs permutations ... I build my module using this command clean install -Dgwt.compiler.skip=true -Dgwt.draftCompile=true -Dgwt.compiler.localWorkers=8 in Intellij

Comment: If it is compiling, it goes somewhere, you just don't know where it is yet. If you tell it to skip, you don't need draft or localworkers, so try not telling it to skip, and see what the output. If you skip, there can be no generated output. It looks like you have two problems "why are my permutations not limited as i expect" and "why is my dev mode building when i try to turn on the non-gwt server".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my problem,

The problem was the -war property didn't point on the good directory

**PATH_TO_MY_DEV_DIRECTORY/MY_GWT_MODULE/target/v2**

instead of

**PATH_TO_MY_DEV_DIRECTORY/MY_PROJECT/MY_GWT_MODULE/target/v2**

So now, in Intellij I have 3 Configurations :

- The compilation server (GWT configuration) with Dev Mode Parameters as : -noserver -war "PATH_TO_MY_DEV_DIRECTORY/MY_PROJECT/MY_GWT_MODULE/target/v2"/
- a maven which builds my war, with Run as : clean install -Dgwt.compiler.skip=true
- a jetty configuration with before launch parameter with my maven configuration

And it works fine now

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid multiple permutation by collapsing all properties in the gwt.xml
which will merge all permutations into one

```
<collapse-all-properties/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your project is not set up correctly.  What version of GWT are you using.  Is this dev mode "Super Dev Mode" or the old dev mode?

> Is it possible to avoid permutations while launching the jetty ?

There should not be permuations being generated when the web server (jetty) launches.  Only when you open the page in your browser should the code server run the GWT compiler to compile the module and then bind to *one* user agent based on your browser type, and that 1 permutation is then compiled.

Comment: Hello, I am using gwt 2.9.0 with super dev mode

Comment: initially in my endpoint the script pointing to MyModule.nocache.js was MyModule/MyModule.nocache.js I tried http://127.0.0.1:9876/MyModule/MyModule.nocache.js instead, I have others errors (Cors and css files not found) I don't know how to solve this if this is the good way to start the web server

Comment: Ok so I think 127.0.0.1:9876/MyModule/MyModule.nocache.js is ok now but the client is calling my rpc on 127.0.0.1:9876 instead of 127.0.0.1:8080 do you know what I am missing ?

Comment: The codeserver runs (by default) on port 9876.  Your webserver (jetty) is running on port 8080.  In your browser you access your HTML page localhost:8080/MyWebapp/index.html .  That HTML page references your GWT JS file thus:  <script type="text/javascript" src="MyWebapp/WebWebapp.nocache.js"></script>

Comment: ok but when I start my webserver the directory MyWebapp is not generate is it normal and when I use the bookmarklet Dev Mode On it didn't find any GWT Module, theese modules are set in the MyWebapp/WebWebapp.nocache.js generate by the code server

Comment: The codeserver needs to be run first.  When it has fully started, you run the webserver.  When it has started, go to your HTML page in browser

Comment: Yes I always start the codeserver first and then the webserver but then, when I click the bookmaklet Dev Mode On on 127.0.0.1:8080 I still have the message Can't find any GWT Modules on this page. it looks like this problem in 2014 https://groups.google.com/g/google-web-toolkit/c/p9BGyLxiLkE

Comment: the "Dev Mode On" option should only appear on the codeserver page, 127.0.0.1:9876.   When you go to 127.0.0.1:8080 it should automatically compile and present your webapp

Comment: I wonder if your *.gwt.xml file has a <add-linker> property lingering around from an earlier version of GWT?  Normally with GWT 2.7 onwards you just want to use the default linker, so you don't want that tag in there.

Comment: Well it can't compile because no MyModule directory with MyModule.nocache.js and other files is generated because of the option If I remove the parameter -Dgwt.compiler.skip=true from my maven build it's ok but it runs permutations so I don't know what to do